# How to invoke default behaviour when using AFNetworking's setQueryStringSerializationWithBlock

Tags: ios, afnetworking, url-encoding

I need to prevent URL encoding of one parameter value for one HTTP request in our app since it has already been encoded before being passed to AFNetworking.*

It seems like the obvious way to do this would be to use setQueryStringSerializationWithBlock on AFHTTPRequestSerializer. However, I can not figure out how to hand over to AFNetworking to do the default serialization for the cases where I don't need custom handling.

I.e. I need to be able to say (pseudo code):

```
[sessionManager.requestSerializer setQueryStringSerializationWithBlock:
    ^NSString *(NSURLRequest *request, NSDictionary *parameters, NSError *__autoreleasing *error)
    {
        if (request is DFP request and parameter is cust_params)
        {
            // do special handling
        }
        else
        {
            // do standard URL encoding for the parameter
            // how?
        }
    }];
```

Essentially, for the else case, I would like to do what AFURLRequestSerialization.requestBySerializingRequest does, which is to call the static function:

```
AFQueryStringFromParametersWithEncoding(parameters, self.stringEncoding);
```

This is however not exposed outside of the AFURLRequestSerialization.m implementation file so I cannot call it.

What is the proper course of action here?

*The parameter in question is the cust_params parameter for a DFP ad-serving call, see: https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1080597

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AFQueryStringFromParametersWithEncoding` is private, but its implementation is exposed through the default `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` implementation of request parameter serialization using URL encoding. Just take the value from another instance of that in your block.

Comment: Right, so I need to create another instance and use requestBySerializingRequest? That does seem to work fine, thanks.

Comment: can you provide an example of this implementation?